# moves past the things that don’t work

Tags: meaning

> Thankfully, the show **moves past the things that don’t work**, solving the Caspere murder quite quickly (the orphaned daughter of the diamond jewellers did it) and ploughing on in an extended ninety-minute episode.*

<sup>([source](http://www.independent.co.uk/arts-entertainment/tv/reviews/true-detective-season-2-finale-review-a-confident-chaotic-end-to-the-series-10449356.html))</sup>

What does "the show moves past the things that don't work" exactly mean in the clause above? Can I paraphrase it this way?

> The last episode of the TD 2 is drawing quickly to a close and the narrative does not deal with motives that are irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Work" here is used in the general sense of "functioning correctly" to refer to aspects that work well artistically and make the show more enjoyable. So they're "moving past" (or spending less time trying to follow up on) the parts that don't really fit and aren't really good.